# How to extract the year from a Python datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to extract the year from the current date using Python.

In C#, this looks like:

```
 DateTime a = DateTime.Now() 
 a.Year
```

What is required in Python?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

It's in fact almost the same in Python.. :-)

```
import datetime
year = datetime.date.today().year
```

Of course, date doesn't have a time associated, so if you care about that too, you can do the same with a complete datetime object:

```
import datetime
year = datetime.datetime.today().year
```

(Obviously no different, but you can store datetime.datetime.today() in a variable before you grab the year, of course).

One key thing to note is that the time components can differ between 32-bit and 64-bit pythons in some python versions (2.5.x tree I think).  So you will find things like hour/min/sec on some 64-bit platforms, while you get hour/minute/second on 32-bit.

Comment: **datetime.datetime.today().year** did not work for Python 3.

It returned an error _AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'_.

I had to use **datetime.today().year**

Comment: @twumm, that was because you imported datetime as "from datetime import datetime". If you had done simply "import datetime", the solution will work fine. It is exactly the same as you have it.

Answer (score 36):

```
import datetime
a = datetime.datetime.today().year
```

or even (as [Lennart suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133147/how-to-extract-the-year-from-a-python-datetime-object#comment950702_1133171))

```
a = datetime.datetime.now().year
```

or even

```
a = datetime.date.today().year
```

Comment: Although now() feels more natural on a datetime.
datetime.date.today().year, maybe. :)

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, and I guess it does feel more "accurate" with respect to time, where today() might seem to imply a precision of days. Weird that (at least in 2.5.4) datetime.today() and datetime.now() do the same thing

Comment: They're not quite the same, datetime.now() accepts a timezone object, while datetime.today() just calls fromtimestamp(time.time()), and so today() will always be in whatever Python thinks your local timezone is, whereas you can get now() to tell you slightly more interesting things.

Answer (score 21):

The other answers to this question seem to hit it spot on.  Now how would you figure this out for yourself without stack overflow?  Check out [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/), an interactive Python shell that has tab auto-complete.

```
> ipython
import Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Nov  6 2007, 16:54:01)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.8.2.svn.r2750 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: now=datetime.datetime.now()
In [3]: now.
```

press tab a few times and you'll be prompted with the members of the "now" object:

```
now.__add__           now.__gt__            now.__radd__          now.__sub__           now.fromordinal       now.microsecond       now.second            now.toordinal         now.weekday
now.__class__         now.__hash__          now.__reduce__        now.astimezone        now.fromtimestamp     now.min               now.strftime          now.tzinfo            now.year
now.__delattr__       now.__init__          now.__reduce_ex__     now.combine           now.hour              now.minute            now.strptime          now.tzname
now.__doc__           now.__le__            now.__repr__          now.ctime             now.isocalendar       now.month             now.time              now.utcfromtimestamp
now.__eq__            now.__lt__            now.__rsub__          now.date              now.isoformat         now.now               now.timetuple         now.utcnow
now.__ge__            now.__ne__            now.__setattr__       now.day               now.isoweekday        now.replace           now.timetz            now.utcoffset
now.__getattribute__  now.__new__           now.__str__           now.dst               now.max               now.resolution        now.today             now.utctimetuple
```

and you'll see that **now.year** is a member of the "now" object.

Comment: Also, this: http://docs.python.org/library/datatypes.html
But thank you, I didn't know that about IPython

Comment: Kudos for problem *solving* — complementing the actual solution.

Comment: For those who don't want to install ipython, you could just wrap any function or class with dir to see the possible methods and attributes. Like, 
dir(datetime.datetime.now) would give you the available functions like pressing tab has in ipython.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the year from a (unknown) datetime-object:

```
tijd = datetime.datetime(9999, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)

>>> tijd.timetuple()
time.struct_time(tm_year=9999, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, tm_hour=23, tm_min=59, tm_sec=59, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=-1)
>>> tijd.timetuple().tm_year
9999
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to go through `timetuple()`; all datetime objects allow access to `.year` and [other expected attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year) directly.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to extract the year as follows.

```
from datetime import datetime

year = datetime.today().year
```