# How to fix datetime TypeError in python

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-iam

I'm pulling cert information out of IAM in AWS and trying to format the expiration date. However, when trying to slice up the date, i'm getting the error TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I'm sure there is probably an obvious fix, but i'm not having much luck.

```py
conn = boto3.client('iam')
iamcerts = conn.list_server_certificates()
response = iamcerts['ServerCertificateMetadataList']
for i in response:
    year  = int(i['Expiration'][0:4])
    month = int(i['Expiration'][5:7])
    day = int(i['Expiration'][8:10])
    exp = date(year, month, day)
    daysleft = exp - today
```

> File "test2.py", line 39, in 
>       year  = int(i['Expiration'][0:4])
>   TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

What I wanted to do was slice off the year, month and day and assign them to the corresponding variables in order to find out how much time is left until the cert expires.

Comment: You're attempting to slice a datetime object as though it were a string. You can convert it to a string and access it this way, or you canuse the access methods for the attributes you're trying to pull out, `.year`, `.day`, `.month`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract the year from a Python datetime object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133147/how-to-extract-the-year-from-a-python-datetime-object)

Comment: `i['Expiration']` is what the error message says it is, an instance of `datetime.datetime`, *not* a `str`. Consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) for how to extract the desired data from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Got the desired outcome using the following:

```
datestring = i['Expiration']
year  = int(datestring.year)
month = int(datestring.month)
day = int(datestring.day)
```